# lenovo vive a7010 não funciona no android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Eu tentei de tudo para fazer funcionar o smartphone a7010 da Lenovo, literalmente nada resolveu, já tive alguns problemas com a Motorola, mas algo que um simples Driver já resolva, porém, este smartphone não me ajuda, o ANdroid Studio não o reconhece de maneira alguma, alguém já teve problemas com ele?

Comment: Já viu isto: https://androidmtk.com/download-lenovo-usb-drivers?

Comment: Instalou o drive da google_usb no gerenciador de dispositivos do pc?

Comment: Fiz o procedimento de instalação do google_usb, não tinha antes, porém, ele funcionou antes de instalar, muito estranho... estou instalando tudo

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se o Android Studio que não está reconhecendo (o que acho pouco provável) , para isso abra o terminal do Android Studio e digite `adb devices`, se não aparecer, o problema provavelmente é que a Lenovo, como muitas outras fabricantes orientais, usam drivers "genéricos" que muitas vezes não são reconhecidos.

Antes de mais nada, o ideal é eliminar alguns pontos que podem fazer com que o adb não reconheça o despositivo.

1. Verifique se a depuração está ativa nas opções de desenvolvedores
2. Verifique nas opções de armazenamento se está selecionado MTP.
3. Reinicie o dispositivo e coloque o cabo usb logo após aparecer a mensagem "Lenovo"
4. Verifique no adb devices se não apareceu na lista
5. Verifique no gerenciador de discos se o dispositivo aparece como não identificado, caso apareça monte ele.

Normalmente estes passos resolvem. :)